# Is it bad practice to have power lines on a PCB instead of a plane

Tags: voltage, power, pcb, trace

I am designing a PCB and am wondering what the downsides are to having a 5V trace instead of a plane.

Comment: What components will be on the PCB, and what is is its purpose?

Comment: This depends on all of the width of the trace, the current drawn, the time domain variation of the current draw, the "loop area" between that path and the return path (through power plane or whatever) and the requirements the circuit must meet, both for its own behavior and in terms of radiated interference.  Good designs can sometimes be made without, additionally it's possible to make a copper pour which isn't actually effective.

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking the question, then you should be using traces.

A power plane is only a sensible option when you have particular problems to solve, and have already committed to a multi-layer board.

Use a PCB calculator for your intended finished copper thickness to make sure your traces are wide enough to carry the current you intend.

Your number one priority is to make sure you have a good ground on your board, and that you have a ground conductor under or near to all signal and power conductors, and a path for ground current following the path the signal current takes. A ground doesn't need to be a plane either, especially not on two-layer boards, but often is.